# Using a variable in a query

Tags: c#, database

I am trying to set up a query for my dataset in C# using a variable for the filter. For example I am trying to only display a specific account number and his balance, with a local variable being the account number used as a filter for that exact one. Am I going about this the wrong way?

I am in no stretch of the imagination a real programmer, I am in a bind and have skimmed along using a guide to programming in C# and the limited brain power I have (which is now running on empty) :)

I also would like to alter the database information using a button with an eventhandler to add specific amounts a cell that was queried. Am I doomed for my lack of knowledge on hard coding or can I actually pull this off?

Sincerely,
noobish engineer trying to program... or Jev

Comment: Hi Jev  can you tell us are you using code behinds?

Comment: Are you using .NET 3.5? If so, LINQ to DataSet is going to be the easiest and most reliable way to do the query - assuming you've already got all the data in a DataSet.

Comment: Getting all the data into dataset is bad idea, imho. Imagine that you have table with 10.000 rows and you need just 5 rows which are valid. Now you load 10.000 rows to dataset and then select 5 with linq. Looks like waste to me.

Answer (score 3):

When you setup your dataset query you can do something like this;

```
SELECT Name FROM TableNames WHERE Name = @Variable
```

Have a look at [this link for more info](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/sql_in_csharp.aspx)

It might be worth having a look into SQL injection attack too, [click here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/SqlInjectionAttacks.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

```
SqlCommand cmd = new sqlCommand("select * from table1 where column1 = @value", connection);
cmd.parameters.add(new SqlParameters("@value", "yourvalue"));
SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
while (dr.read())
{

   //code here!

}
```

I Hope this will be usefull!

Comment: You might want to edit your answer to format the code portion as code so that it is easier to read.

Comment: I tried out your code but  the SqlParameters gave me an error, so I renamed it to SqlParameter.. Also.. read should be Read

Answer (score 0):

Once upon a time, I've written a little article on why you should definitely use parameters in SQL statements.
(I've written it in response to the fact that I saw way to many people using string concat enation to write their queries).

You can find it here:
http://fgheysels.blogspot.com/2005/12/avoiding-sql-injection-and-date.html

Answer (score -3):

You could just use the variable to generate your SQL-Query dynamically, but beware of SQL-Injection - be really sure, that your variable may not contain SQL-Statements.

You could use a function, that builds and returns your SQL-Query like this, with the variable for the filter as parameter:

```
internal string BuildSQLQueryForAccount(int account)
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.Append("SELECT * ");
    sb.Append("FROM Accounts ");
    sb.AppendFormat("WHERE AccountNumber = {0}", account);
    return sb.ToString();
}
```

Comment: Bad idea, simply on principle. Why take the risk of the code being copied and used for a string parameter, leading to SQL injection? Parameterised SQL isn't hard, and it's worth using it ubiquitously (except for the *very* few places where you can't, such as parameterising the table names).

Comment: Well, I added the hint for SQL-Injection, so why the downvote?

Comment: Because it's giving a bad example which can easily be copy-pasted when SQL parameterisation is a much, much better solution.